# How to install Ubuntu 14.04 OS in Hp laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 OS with i5 processor

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, virtualbox, 18.04, intel

Recently I got a new HP laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 OS and i5 processor.
But for a particular purpose I want Ubuntu 14.04.

We tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 in the new laptop but due to driver compatibility it's not getting installed. Can anyone guide me?

1. Is it possible to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a device with i5 processor?
2. If we use VirtualBox, will we be able to install 14.04 on this machine?
3. Is there any alternative method to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop with i5 processor?

Comment: can you add some details as to what driver compatibility issues you identified? i5 has been around for a long time and while it's definitely plausible that the newer kernel has a better i915 (or whatever driver the i5 uses), I find it pretty weird that your installation could actually fail because of some CPU driver incompatibility when the CPU isn't a new model.

Comment: I did it without any problem on an ASUS i5. Did you create a bootable usb ? can you boot on 'try without install' mode ?

Comment: @Zanna Due to Upstart i am facing issue. I need upstart to run my project, but as higher version of ubuntu are using systemd. I am not sure what driver issue because system admin told that its not installing

Comment: @Dadep No, we tried to install it using CD. How you installed it can you please share the steps? system admin told me that its due to some drivers issue we cant able to install ubuntu14.04. After coming to 85% installation stops

Comment: @shree, you can try boot on usb (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 or https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) then try to use in "try without installing" mode. Tell us if you get some error doing this.

Comment: @Dadep By installing like, does 14.04 get installed in laptop though we have driver compatibility issue which we faced while installing ubuntu 14.04 from CD ? Sorry for late reply

Comment: @Dadep I purchased laptop with ubuntu 18.04 OS. Later due to project requirement i need to install ubuntu 14.04 because i need upstart service for my project.  somehow install ubuntu 16.04 but that also not supporting upstart service. Any solution for this ? Please help

Comment: @shree did you try to create with any other computer a bootable usb flash drive ? Do you get any error message ? If you can boot in try without install mode it will be easier to get information about the issue and maybe fix it. Also upstart have been replace by systemd. information here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: @Dadep Since i had doubt i still didn't try bootable usb flash drive. So first i need to make bootable pendrive and then try to boot it in my new laptop without install mode and send you the details if i get any issue. Correct ?

Comment: @shree yes exactly

Comment: @Dadep I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 without install mode, after that i get blank screen

Comment: @shree do you get any error message ? and when you just try to install ? any error message ?

Comment: @Dadep It just go to drak screen and does nothing for both install and non install mode

Comment: this is very strange, some question : Why don't you adapt you app to run with systemd instead of upstart ? did you try to install other version of ubuntu ? did you try to format before installing ?

Comment: @Dadep I didnt format before installing. I am not sure how to run the project in systemd which is set for upstart